# How can I make the swipe action for a carousel on mobile

Tags: javascript, carousel

I've got a carousel of a twitter feed on my website.  Got it so you can navigate the 3 slides/tweets through the carousel dots.

I need to add a swipe function so when on mobile I can swipe my finger left to right to browse the tweets.  Tried looking for a solution and most answers result in suggesting a plugin.  Since my twitter feed is in an iframe it's proven problematic trying to initialise its content with a carousel plugin.

For that reason I've used a vanilla JavaScript carousel from off of W3.

But I have no idea how I can get a swipe function to work with the code I have.

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.left = "-100%"; 
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.left = "20px"; 
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I want to get up in running fast, I use iScroll. But you've probably heard that one (it isss a pretty solid option).

The vanilla way is to use plain javascript touch event listeners + functions to translate your slide elements. Specifically you write functions for touchStart touchMove and touchEnd. You would need to identify if you are on mobile and switch the events to work this way (and not if on desktop).